# No such file or directory in file /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I wrote my first composer package, however when I tried to test it by adding to a Laravel project, I received the following error:

```
ErrorException: include(/var/www/vendor/composer/../xxx/register-com-client/src/RegisterServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

Here's the `composer.json` for my package:

```
{
"name": "xxx/register-com-client",
"description": "",
"type": "library",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "xxx\\Register_com\\": "src/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "xxx\\Register_com\\RegisterServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

And in my laravel project, I'm calling one of the functions in my `register-com-client` like this:

```
$registerService = new RegisterService();
$response = $registerService->getDomainProductId($input['sld'], $input['tld']);
```

I linked to my package locally in my laravel project like this (in `composer.json`)

```
{
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/Users/dannixxxx/xxx/register-com-client",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you can composer update?

Comment: @thisiskelvin I did `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Is your package local or remote on packagist?

Comment: @thisiskelvin local, I used a `symlink` to install. I updated my description with `composer.json` in my laravel project.

Comment: Are you sure `/Users` is the first volume of your local machine? You can confirm the full path by `cd`ing into your folder in the terminal and typing `pwd` (Print working directory).

Comment: Yes, it is, I tried `pwd` and it's `/Users`